# Flutter: JsObject call document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, jsobject

How we can call getElementById using JsObject in flutter, tried below but not worked

```
import 'dart:js' as js;

var msg = js.context['window'].callMethod(
              'document.getElementById', ["feeds"]);
var msg = js.context.callMethod(
              'document.getElementById', ["feeds"]);

Giving error 

NoSuchMethodError: 'callMethod'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the method was supposed to be `call()` only, as such the error says, there is no `callMethod()` in JS, if I am being correct.